# Kotlin Spring Boot Many to Many relation ship with additional value in JoinTable

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I have two kotlin data-classes which are in a many to many relation ship. The resulting junction-table should also have a extra property. Now how would you implement that with the use of kotlin data-classes? 
I found this tutorial on how to implement them with java: 
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many
Unfortunatly, I wasn't able to implement it with kotlin data-classes withtout hibernate throwing an error upon starting my application.

Is there a wey to properly implement this with data-classes?

Comment: Entities shouldn't be implemented using data classes in the first place. But anyway, if you don't share the code nor theexception, we can't possibly help.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't throw an exception. And as said the code didn't work at all. Wouldn't it be possible to just share an example? Also what speaks against using data classes?